# The download attribute in anchor tag is not working in HTML

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Anchor Tag-->
        <a href="./HG.jpg" download>Download image</a>
        <a target="_blank" href="./HG.jpg" download>Download image</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am running this in Chrome browser but the file is not being downloaded. The file is in the same folder as the html file.
I also tried to go through the previously answered same question but it still isn't working.
The image opens in both cases; the one where I have used target attribute opens the image in a new tab and the one without target attribute opens in the same tab. But after that nothing happens. The download is not initiated. I even checked the browser download settings but they are not the reason for this.
I would really appreciate if someone can guide me how to make this work.

Comment: What exactly happens when you click the link? (no visible change/the image opens in a new tab/a download window appears but fails somehow, etc)

Comment: @DBS The image opens in both cases. The one where I have used target attribute opens the image in a new tab and the one without target attribute opens in the same tab. But after that nothing happens. The download is not initiated. I even checked the browser download settings but they are not the reason for this.

Comment: Are the files you are attempting to download on the same origin as your HTML file?

Comment: @MfyDev Yes, the image is in the same parent folder as the index.html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same issue as the not-working `fetch()` - it's a security feature that the browser treats two `file:///` paths as different origins. And because the `download` attribute only works on resources of the same origin, it doesn't work. To make these things work, you need to use a localhost server.

Comment: Yes, it worked when I installed Live Server extension in VS code. But is there any other way to solve this bug without installing such extensions? And what causes this bug? I am just asking for knowledge.

Comment: It's actually not a bug, but a security feature (sorry my bad). There are historical reasons for it. **But** it's not implemented in Firefox and Chrome has a CLI flag to allow the same-origin policy for `file:///` urls.